# DAX formula for sales sum for each day of previous n days

Tags: powerbi, dax

Given a table *FACT* in Power BI with three columns *Date*, *Category* and *Sales* I am looking for a DAX function that for each day returns the sum of the sales of its previous *n* days.   
Lets assume *n* = 2, that means for day 01/04/2020 my measure should return the sum of the sales of the days 01/02/2020 and 01/03/2020.
Here is a small example:

```
Date        Category  Sales 
01/01/2020  A         1
01/01/2020  B         3
01/02/2020  B         2
01/03/2020  B         1
01/04/2020  A         0
01/05/2020  B         10
01/06/2020  B         7
```

What I want is

```
Date        MyMeasure 
01/01/2020  0 
01/02/2020  4
01/03/2020  6
01/04/2020  3
01/05/2020  1
01/06/2020  10
```

I later would then like to use the Category as a filter and in my case *n* is 365.

I tried the following

```
MyMeasure = 
VAR FROM_DATE =
    DATEADD ( FACT[DATE], 0, DAY )
VAR SALES_365 =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( FACT[SALES] ),
        DATESINPERIOD ( FACT[DATE], FROM_DATE, 365, DAY )
    )
RETURN
    SALES_365
```

but got an error that a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the variable FROM_DATE, in which DATEADDD returned a column of dates and not a single value.
That said you don't really need a variable for that, you can just use a simple subtraction and `DATESBETWEEN(DateCol, DateFrom,DateTo)`

```
MyMeasure = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( FACT[SALES] ),
    DATESBETWEEN('FACT'[DATE],MAX(FACT[DATE])-2,MAX(FACT[DATE])-1)
)
```

Comment: Your suggested solution results in the error 'The MAX function only accepts a column reference as an argument.' so that didn't work.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice what FROM_DATE was. I'll edit the answer, the problem was the same anyway as DATEADD return a list of dates and not a single value

Comment: Great that works, thank you. Even though I would have expected that this formula returns the same value for every day, since MAX(FACT[DATE]) is always the current day., isn't it? Could you explain, why MAX(FACT[DATE]) seemingly refers to each day in its context?

Comment: That's because you are showing the date in the table, and therefore the "context" changes for each row. Just put the following measures in the table and see the returned result `DateFrom=MAX(FACT[DATE])-2` and `DateTo=MAX(FACT[DATE])-1`